# Incorrect Answer Count on Profile

Tags: support, profile-page, statistics

The answer count on [my profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3898/ian-dunn) is 10, but there are only 9 answers listed below it. It's been like that for awhile (e.g., it listed 7 and only linked to 6, etc). Is this a bug, or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. You have two answers to one of the questions; search the page for (2).

Comment: Ah, that's it. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.